# Open last closed file in a new tab in Vim

Tags: linux, vim, vi, macvim

I know I can open the last closed (`:q`) file in Vim by using `:e#`. This will open the file in the current tab. How would I perform the same task but open the file in a new Vim tab. Also I am interested in how to open the file in a new split instead of the current tab.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`#` is simply an Ex special character that will be replaced with the name of the alternate file. Do an `:ls`, and the alternate file will be marked with a `#` there also.

`#` can similarly be used with `:tabnew` and `split`. In the examples below I'll use `:tabe` in place of `:tabnew` as `:tabe` is a shorter alias for `:tabnew` (search for either in the help docs):

- To open the alternate file in a new tab: `:tabe#`
- To open the file in a new split: `:split#`; this can be abbreviated to `:sp#`, and `:vsp#` for a vertical split.

Using a buffer *number* from `:ls`, e.g. buffer number *5* you can also:

- open the buffer in a split with `:sp#5`; alternately `:sb5` if the `switchbuf` option contains the `newtab` specifier - see `:help switchbuf`
- open the buffer in a vertical split with `:vsp #5` (there is no `:vsb`)
- open the buffer in a new tab with `:tabe #5`

Comment: If I get the buffer number from :ls of the file I want to load, what would be the tabnew format to load that file in a tab?

Comment: The `#` Ex special character is *not* a register!  It is one of special characters which is subject to expansion at places where a file name can be used in Ex commands.  See also `:help cmdline-special`.

Comment: By the way, why do use `<kbd>` to format Ex command lines instead of `\``?  It is better to use `<kbd>` for typesetting separate keys and shortcuts.

Comment: The `:sb1` command will open a buffer in a new tab page, if the `switchbuf` option contains the `newtab` specifier.  See `:help switchbuf`.

Comment: @ib thanks for the info and suggestion. I've updated the answer and added info about `#N`. You'll notice from the edit history that I initially had the ex commands in backticks `; I'm still developing  formatting habits here, particularly for vim questions, and your point re: kbd is a good one.

Comment: `:tabe` can also be used, which is shorter than `:tabnew`

Comment: Thanks @DrumM I edited the answer to shorten the commands and reference the equivalence of `:tabe` and `:tabnew`

Answer (score 6):

You don't necessarily have to leave normal mode to open the alternate buffer in a new window:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> **opens the alternate buffer in a horizontal split**.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> opens the current buffer in a new tab (Shift-T, that is).

So, one solution to your title question is the following combo.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>: **opens the alternate buffer in a new tab.**

Note that for the caret "^" in the first command you don't have to release the Control key and you don't have to press Shift, just hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> then strike <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> (where the caret is located on many English keyboard layouts).